# proc_open not writing to STDIN on simple C program

Tags: php, c

Below is php script that runs program (test.exe- code at end) using proc_open.
It just hangs in the browser.
None of the two files are written to the directory by the test program. But if I take out the stream_get_contents line and add it in after writing to STDIN it echos the STDOUT. None of the two files write though, and I don't understand why. Any suggestions?
EDIT: `echo fgetc($pipes[1]);` doesn't block... hmm

```
<?
test(234);

function test($number) {
  $descriptorspec = array(
     0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
     1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
     2 => array("file","whatever.log", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
  );

    $process = proc_open("cd \"C:/\" && test.exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

fwrite($pipes[0],$number);
fclose($pipes[0]);

    return !$return_value;
  }
}
?>
```

C program (Works as expected from cmdline):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
int i;
FILE *ofp;

printf("Please enter an integer number");
fflush ( stdout );
scanf("%d", &i);

ofp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fprintf(ofp, "%d", i);
fclose(ofp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out:
You need to specify the buffer for freads on windows it seems:

```
echo fread($pipes[1], 1024);
```